# Layout.css no longer being recognised after change in url for web application

Tags: css, spring-security, tapestry

Hi am using Tapestry 5 to create a planning web application and to get around a spring security issue I have changed the url pattern in org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter from /* to /planning/* 
After altering the corresponding urls and file paths in any Java / .tml files accordingly the web application works as itended, however my css stylesheet is no longer being picked up.

I have a Layout.java in a components file and a corresponding Layout.tml, and then a layout.css file in a layout folder in the webapp file (outside of WEB-INF)
The stylesheet is being called in the Layout.java file by @Import(stylesheet="context:layout/layout.css") - this always worked before!

I have tried moving the css file into a planning subdirectry planning/layout/layout.css but this still doesnt seem to make a difference!

Web.xml

```
  <display-name>Planning Tapestry 5 Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>tapestry.app-package</param-name>
    <param-value>com.quartetfs.planning.tapestry</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>app</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/planning/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Layout.java

```
import org.apache.tapestry5.*;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.*;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.*;
import org.apache.tapestry5.BindingConstants;

/**
 * Layout component for pages of Planning Application.
 */
@Import(stylesheet="context:layout/layout.css")
public class Layout
{
    /** The page title, for the <title> element and the <h1> element. */
    @Property
    @Parameter(required = true, defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
    private String title;

    @Property
    private String pageName;

    @Property
    @Parameter(defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
    private String sidebarTitle;

    @Property
    @Parameter(defaultPrefix = BindingConstants.LITERAL)
    private Block sidebar;

    @Inject
    private ComponentResources resources;

    public String getClassForPageName()
    {
      return resources.getPageName().equalsIgnoreCase(pageName)
         ? "current_page_item"
         : null;
    }

    public String[] getPageNames()
    {
      return new String[] { "planning/Index", };// "About", "Contact" }; TODO
    }
}
```

Layout.tml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-     strict.dtd">
<!--

Design by Free CSS Templates
http://www.freecsstemplates.org
Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License

Title      : Concrete
Version    : 1.0
Released   : 20080825
Description: A Web 2.0 design with fluid width suitable for blogs and small websites.
-->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">



    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>${title}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- start header -->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1>
                    <t:pagelink page="planning/index">Project and Resource Planning</t:pagelink>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                   <li t:type="loop" source="pageNames" value="pageName" class="prop:classForPageName">
                        <t:pagelink page="prop:pageName">${pageName}</t:pagelink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end header -->

        <!-- start page -->
        <div id="page">
            <!-- start sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li id="search" style="background: none;">
                    </li>
                    <li t:type="if" test="sidebar">
                        <h2>${sidebarTitle}</h2>
                        <div class="sidebar-content">
                            <t:delegate to="sidebar"/>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- end sidebar -->

            <!-- start content -->
            <div id="content">
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2>${title}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <t:body/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end content --> 

            <br style="clear: both;"/>
        </div>
        <!-- end page -->

        <!-- start footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <p class="legal">
                &copy;2009 com.example. All Rights Reserved.
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Design by
                <a href="http://www.freecsstemplates.org/">Free CSS Templates</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Icons by
                <a href="http://famfamfam.com/">FAMFAMFAM</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- end footer -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to move the layout.css file; if Tapestry can't find it, then it will throw an exception when loading the pages containing the Layout component.

When you have a problem like this, it is very useful to view the source of the rendered page, and see what the requests and reponses are.

I suspect that the URL for the stylsheet is coming out as "/assets/..." ... which is not picked up by Tapestry (due to how your filter mapping is set up), and you'll see a 404 error.

It is necessary to inform Tapestry that you have placed the application in a sub-folder (alas, the Servlet API does not provide introspection into how you have things configured in your web.xml).

http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-tapestry.applicationfolder

Once Tapestry knows the application folder, it can build proper URLs.

Comment: There's even more notes about this exact case at the bottom of the documentation page:  http://tapestry.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-SegregatingApplicationsIntoFolders

Comment: Geat, changing the application folder worked perfectly, and I could revert back to all my original file paths too - a much neater solution. Thanks a lot!